# discord.py, im making a bot responce that responds to you depending on how you feel, but only prints what in the 1st if statement - the probl000000

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio

```
@commands.command(aliases=['im', 'i'])
async def userfeeling(self, ctx, *other):
    if other or ctx == 'bad' or 'awful' or 'sad' or 'unhappy' or 'upset' or 'crying' or 'very 
                        bad':
        await ctx.send(random.choice(hru_bad_responce))
        print("path1")

    elif other or ctx == 'fine' or 'im fine':
        await ctx.send('i detect lies')
        print("path2")

    elif other or ctx == 'good' or 'great' or 'amazing' or 'im okay' or 'okay' or 'happy':
        await ctx.send(random.choice(hru_good_responce))
        print("path3")

    await ctx.send('{} arguments: {}'.format(len(other), ', '.join(other)))
```

what it does:

me: *im upset
bot (outputs the 1st if statement)

me: *im fine
bot (outputs the 1st if statement)

me: *im good
bot (outputs the 1st if statement)

what it needs to do:

me: *im upset
bot (outputs the 1st if statement)

me: *im fine
bot (outputs the 2ndif statement)

me: *im good
bot (outputs the 3rdif statement)

Comment: the last word in the title is supposed to say the problem, its dark so i missclicked and tried to delete but accidently hit enter which submitted the question.

Comment: `if other or ctx == 'bad' or 'awful' or 'sad' or 'unhappy'` This is the wrong way to test for multiple values.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/494134

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-single-value)